# Coral Dev Board - Can't get demo to run

Tags: google-coral, mendel-os

I recently purchased a used dev board to start working on. I managed to flash it with Mendel 5 (Eagle) enabled SSH and followed the instructions on the get started without any issue until I tried the demo.

I can't get it to work at all!

If I run edgetpu_demo --stream

I get:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Press 'q' to quit.
Press 'n' to switch between models.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/edgetpu_detect_server", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('edgetpuvision==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'edgetpu_detect_server')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/detect_server.py", line 33, in main
    run_server(add_render_gen_args, render_gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/apps.py", line 43, in run_server
    camera = make_camera(args.source, next(gen), args.loop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/detect.py", line 144, in render_gen
    engines, titles = utils.make_engines(args.model, DetectionEngine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpuvision/utils.py", line 53, in make_engines
    engine = engine_class(model_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu/detection/engine.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(model_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/edgetpu/basic/basic_engine.py", line 92, in __init__
    self._engine = BasicEnginePythonWrapper.CreateFromFile(model_path)
RuntimeError: No Edge TPU device detected!
```

running as root gives me:

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Press 'q' to quit.
Press 'n' to switch between models.
job-working-directory: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(edgetpu_detect_server:7283): Gtk-WARNING **: 02:24:31.914: cannot open display:
```

Which seems closer but no idea how to fix either. I've searched as much as I can (added the user the plugdev, made sure everything was installed correctly)

Any ideas? Pretty sure if this doesn't work something is fairly broken.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out, this is definitely not a good sign..

```
RuntimeError: No Edge TPU device detected!
```

Sounds like the board some how lost access to the edgetpu, could you send us an email to coral-support@google.coon this issue?